# Exporting MySQL database from XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I need to send my website with the MySQL database. I have done the website and MySQL database in XAMPP but don’t know how to send the database.

Comment: You could Google "export mySQL"

Comment: See e.g. http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have 2 possible ways to do that

- by command line

> backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] >
>   dumpfilename.sql
>
> restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] <
>   dumpfilename.sql

- or use phpmyadmin (usually installed with XAMP), or something like that and export it from browser

Answer (score 29):

Exporting MySQL database from xampp

The command line :

1. First of all open command prompt
2. Syntax:-

Import Database  :-
`D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql – u root -p databasename < D:/test.sql (sql file name)`

Export Database  :-
`D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p databasename > D:/text.sql(sql file name)`

Comment: Export command works but import doesn't work. However answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL ships with [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), and so does [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/). It’s used for [dumping data in SQL format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html), and its easiest appliance might be dumping all databases into one SQL dump file, executing it in`cmd.exe`:

> **`mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql`**

For XAMPP, you need to provide the username`(-u root)`as well as a database name`(test)`:

> **`mysqldump -u=root test > xampp-test-db.sql`**

As a practical, verbose example:

> **`D:\xampp\mysql\bin> mysqldump.exe --user=root --password=pwd myDatabase > C:\myBackup.sql`**

Note that`mysqldump` has [extensive, powerful options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#idm139954507101696) for a wide variety of backup applications.

Since it generates SQL scripts, recovery is easy; see [*Reloading SQL-Format Backups*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html).