# XAMPP mysql stopped working after I change permissions

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So, some backstory. I was working on a file upload script. But xampp wouldn't let me because it didn't have the permission (apparantly). So, I changed the permissions to (btw, I'm on a mac) everybody: read and write. But, after this, phpmyadmin stopped working. I changed back to everybody: read only. But still it wouldn't work.

From what I see, the permissions and such are all as it was before, when it worked. Yet, it wont work. This is starting to make me pretty pissed, to be honest. I have had similar problems before where mysql wont work. In my past, I have reinstalled xampp. But.. I have a pretty big database and I really dont want to lose it.

So now to the question, how could I possible make mysql work again? Or, if thats a no go, how can I save my database?

With kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have enough details to help you with your first question.

With regards to your second question: [Exporting MySQL database from XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923150/exporting-mysql-database-from-xampp). You basically can do an export in the command line now and then just import the same sql file later, when you reinstall xamp, for example.

Hope this helps.